# Passing objects vs. Static members

Tags: java, class, static

In Java, is it better to use static members when modifying one variable in different scopes / modules, or to pass an object using arguments?

Comment: Too general question to answer (and wrong place to ask), but common wisdom would be to pass an object explicitly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a technical question but a question of design. When you design your class, you separate the fields in *class properties* and *instance properties*. Here's a simple example:

```
 public class Car {

   // every instance of "Car" has wheels -> static
   public static boolean hasWheels = true;

   // every instance of "Car" has an individual colour -> non static
   public Colour colour; 

   // ...
 }
```

Comment: (if that was the question...)

Comment: @Andreas_D - you've clearly never seen a Reliant Robin :-)

Comment: Seriously, the "not all cars have 4 wheels" issue helps to illustrate why static fields / members are a bad idea in a model.  If `numberOfWheels` had been a `Car` instance method that returned `4`, you could override it to return `3` in the `ReliantRobin` subclass of `Car`.

Comment: Orrr - yes, OK, I change the property. An yes, I *know* that *real* cars may have less or more then four wheels. But I have the feeling, the Lemmons got the point. (and please, lets agree, that vehicles with no wheels are not called cars...)

Answer (score 1):

Java is an object oriented programming language, it generally works best if you use it in an object oriented fashion.

It is not clear what you mean by "modifying one variable in different scopes / modules", but the the answer is (probably) that it is better to avoid using static methods.

It is definitely a bad idea to **expose** fields so that they can be accessed and modified by a static method in a different class.  It break down the classes abstraction boundary, and results in inter-class coupling that is harmful in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

when you used a `static member` you want have a instance of it member in `static memory`, so when another thread change it member value, another thread see last value. for understand it see following sample code:

```
public class Counter
{

      public static int number  = 10;

      public Counter(int c )
      {
           number = c;
      } 

      public static final void main(String[] args)
      {
           Counter counter_1 = new Counter(20);
           Counter counter_2 = new Counter(30);

           System.out.println(counter_1.number);
           System.out.println(counter_2.number);
      }

}
```

When you run this program , see following output:

```
30
30
```

So in static approach `Thread Safely` is a important issue.
but when you used `object passing` approch, any thread has its context (`Thread-Context`) so it changes published in own thread context(also this result depend on if you using or not `Singleton Pattern`)

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton pattern to implements your requirements